# Tip for Trogdor: please eat our homework

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

We have a couple of [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags) on this site. [tips-and-tricks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) and [homework](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) are both meaningless tags: they don't indicate anything about the topic or audience of a question. Even conservative [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is phasing out [`tips-and-tricks`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tips-and-tricks) and [is on the way to getting rid of `homework`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag).

A [pending request to get rid of these tags](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554/killing-a-few-meta-tags-and-please-write-tag-wikis) met no opposition in over a year.

Please kill these meta-tags.

[Images of Trogdor the Burninator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121570/271976). 
[Here's another one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF2GS.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Burninated, but not blacklisted - they're few in number, and really shouldn't be a problem to keep under control.

[Take care of the widows and orphans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged)

Comment: The non-closed orphans are [Jeff's fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418). I've [repeatedly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) [requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79733/please-allow-low-occurence-tags-to-be-declared-persistent) ways to save them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm good with it. Other community members, what do you think?