# Removal of the [failure] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

Speak now if you want to defend the [failure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failure) tag. I believe it to be a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that:

- does not "describe the content of the question"
- can't work as the only tag on a question
- commonly means different things to different people

I will be retagging the existing 57 questions; some of them really aim at [return-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-status); others are about hardware failure; and many are just about some-other-failure-that-needs-to-be-described.

After the tag is cleared out, I believe the tag should be blacklisted.

Comment: I'm not sure "meta-tag" is the word I'd use.  But it certainly doesn't convey much information, because it's very common to ask about something that's failed.  I imagine "network failure" might be mildly interesting to me as a search term...  hmm.  It might be more accurate to say I like "network troubleshooting".  What do we think about the existence of the "troubleshooting" tag?  At least it excludes the ambiguity with "return-status".

Comment: Failures of some sort are what the whole site's about -- failure of expectations or of software or of hardware.  I think that "troubleshooting" smells like a meta tag. Ah! [here's a previous meta discussion of some meta tags](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554/killing-a-few-meta-tags-and-please-write-tag-wikis)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I agree with your logic and IMO it should be removed.

Comment: I have just finished un-tagging questions; [tag:failure] is now empty. Please blacklist it. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller moderators can't blacklist. Only devs/CM's

Comment: Thanks, Braiam! I am *still* bookmarking various meta posts to remind me how this site works. @slm, according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/307535), someone needs to flag this post for moderator attention, or contact the devs personally. I have a cool, refreshing beverage at the ready, so let me know if I should reach out or if you already have. Thanks!